# Error con el header de la tabla al hacer una búsqueda

Tags: php, css, html5, bootstrap

cuando hago la búsqueda, me desaparece el header de mi tabla. Y cuando borro el texto tampoco me vuelve a como estaba. Necesitaría que sea el header sea fijo. Estoy usando bootstrap. 
Si hace falta que suba algún código mas me avisan 
Es una base de datos en la cual hago un listado de integrantes y uso el buscador para encontrarlos facil

Les dejo imágenes de lo que me refiero

Mi tabla (toma datos de una base de datos)

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="myTabla">
                    <tr>
                        <th>No</th>
                        <th>Código</th>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Lugar de nacimiento</th>
                        <th>Fecha de nacimiento</th>
                        <th>Teléfono</th>
                        <th>Cargo</th>
                        <th>Estado</th>
                        <th>Acciones</th>
                    </tr>
```

El código de mi buscador

```
function myFunction() {

            // Declare variables 
            var input = document.getElementById("tableinput");
            var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
            var table = document.getElementById("myTabla");
            var trs = table.tBodies[0].getElementsByTagName("tr");

            // Loop through first tbody's rows
            for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {

                // define the row's cells
                var tds = trs[i].getElementsByTagName("td");

                // hide the row
                trs[i].style.display = "none";

                // loop through row cells
                for (var i2 = 0; i2 < tds.length; i2++) {

                    // if there's a match
                    if (tds[i2].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {

                        // show the row
                        trs[i].style.display = "";

                        // skip to the next row
                        continue;

                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

[image: Imagen 1]
[image: Imagen 2] 
[image: Imagen 3]
[image: Imagen 4]
[image: Imagen 5]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El tema de que te desaparezca el *header* de tu tabla, es porque no lo has definido como tal.

Dentro de la función `myFunction()` tienes una linea que te va a ocultar todos los `<tr>` de que pertenezcan al `<tbody>` de tu tabla, que al no existir van a ser todos (incluyendo el que contiene los `<th>`).

```
trs[i].style.display = "none";
```

Ya que con el bucle `for` iteras por todos los `<tr>` de tu tabla donde `trs[0]` corresponde a donde tienes los `<th>`.

Podrías solucionarlo modificando la estructura de tu tabla para que se asemeje a esta:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="myTabla">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Código</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Lugar de nacimiento</th>
        <th>Fecha de nacimiento</th>
        <th>Teléfono</th>
        <th>Cargo</th>
        <th>Estado</th>
        <th>Acciones</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
  </table>
```

De esa manera en `var trs = table.tBodies[0].getElementsByTagName("tr");` tan solo capturarías los `<tr>` que corresponden al `<tbody>` de tu tabla, dejando inalterables los del `<thead>`.

**Código funcionando en un snniped:**

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
  <label>Buscador</label>
  <input id="tableinput" type="text">
  <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="BUSCAR">

  <table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="myTabla">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Código</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Lugar de nacimiento</th>
        <th>Fecha de nacimiento</th>
        <th>Teléfono</th>
        <th>Cargo</th>
        <th>Estado</th>
        <th>Acciones</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>No 1</td>
        <td>Código 1</td>
        <td>Nombre 1</td>
        <td>Lugar de nacimiento 1</td>
        <td>Fecha de nacimiento 1</td>
        <td>Teléfono 1</td>
        <td>Cargo 1</td>
        <td>Estado 1</td>
        <td>Acciones 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>No 2</td>
        <td>Código 2</td>
        <td>Nombre 2</td>
        <td>Lugar de nacimiento 2</td>
        <td>Fecha de nacimiento 2</td>
        <td>Teléfono 2</td>
        <td>Cargo 2</td>
        <td>Estado 2</td>
        <td>Acciones 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>No 3</td>
        <td>Código 3</td>
        <td>Nombre 3</td>
        <td>Lugar de nacimiento 3</td>
        <td>Fecha de nacimiento 3</td>
        <td>Teléfono 3</td>
        <td>Cargo 3</td>
        <td>Estado 3</td>
        <td>Acciones 3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    // Declare variables 
    var input = document.getElementById("tableinput");
    var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    var table = document.getElementById("myTabla");
    var trs = table.tBodies[0].getElementsByTagName("tr");

    // Loop through first tbody's rows
    for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {

      // define the row's cells
      var tds = trs[i].getElementsByTagName("td");

      // hide the row
      trs[i].style.display = "none";

      // loop through row cells
      for (var i2 = 0; i2 < tds.length; i2++) {

        // if there's a match
        if (tds[i2].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {

          // show the row
          trs[i].style.display = "";

          // skip to the next row
          continue;

        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: te hago dos consultas `trs[i].style.display = "none";` lo borro de la función del script? Y ya funciona? Y entre los <tbody> que debo colocar? Le coloco las variables que deseo que se visualicen?

Comment: El tema es que si elimino `trs[i].style.display = "none"` y agrego el <thead></thead><tbody></tbody> no me hace la búsqueda

Comment: La imagen 4 y 5 es del todo el código que no me deja subir. No se como solucionarlo lo que me mencionas anteriormente

Comment: No entiendo lo que quieres decir, no tendrías que cambiar en nada el **Javascript**, solamente la tabla en tu **HTML** tal y como te dije. Edito mi respuesta para mostrar tu código funcionando.